# Linux tool to overlay MP3 files for use in PHP

Tags: php, audio, mp3

I have been searching the internet with no success for a tool that will allow two mp3 files to be overlaid on top of each other. I have a client who wants to build a service that allows someone to select a music track and a vocal track from a list of files and then have them play together. Her business produces visualisation CD's and I believe this would be the best route as she has hundreds of visualisation mp3 scripts and about 30 backing music. This will allow the merging of these 2 files dynamically and for them to be cached as opposed to doing the manual work on demand.

I have investigated ffmpeg and other tools but these tend to handle cutting/splitting/merging etc, but I have found nothing that will allow me to overlay two audio tracks on top of each other to produce a merged track.

I guess what would be perfect is something along the lines of a command line version of audacity.

Answer (score 4):

Install sox, use the `--combine` switch

```
sox --combine {mix|merge|mix-power} track1.mp3 track2.mp3 output.mp3
```

Use `--volume FACTOR` before an input file name to i.e. keep the background track in the background :-); sox has a lot of other options to mix, match, edit audio files; you can find the [man page online here](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html), to check in advance if you want to gove it a try (you should...).