# Creating your own mp3 from a group of mp3 using PHP

Tags: php, mp3

I have seen this question

[Combine/Concatenate MP3s on Server Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164562/combine-concatenate-mp3s-on-server-using-php)

Just wondering whether there's a way to extend the functionality so that you can not only concatenate but also overlay 2 mp3s? 
Is this possible?

By overlay I mean. 
MP3 A
MP3 B
creates MP3 C

Whose Audio is like

Mp3 A

Mp3 B

simultaneously

Comment: PHP == wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @SDC what would be the right one? PS I'm using windows so..

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359974/linux-tool-to-overlay-mp3-files-for-use-in-php

Comment: Look for an command-line tool to combine MP3-files. You can excecute those commands using PHP.

Comment: @P1nGu1n Can I use SoX to do this?

Comment: Carl, I'm late responding to your reply, but my answer would be the same as @P1nGu1n said; there will be some third party commandline tool that will be perfect for this job. You'll have to research that for yourself though, as I don't know the answer. Once you have your tool, yes you can use PHP to call it.

Comment: @CarlSaldanha I just took a quick look at SoX and that's indeed what you're looking for. Try this for example: `sox song1.mp3 song2.mp3 song3.mp3 output.mp3`